# CMP instruction behaving weirdly if operand is over 127?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, gnu-assembler, machine-code

I wrote this assembly program:

```
.section .data
    1: .asciz "Hello"

.section .text

entry:
    mov $0x07C0, %ax
    add $0x120, %ax
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov 0x100, %sp

    mov $0x7C0, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds

    # mov $1b, %si
    mov $0xE, %ah
    mov $0x0, %si
    mov $0x0, %bx

    push %bp
    mov %sp, %bp
    mov %di, -20(%bp)
    mov %si, -32(%bp)

    movl $0x0, -4(%ebp)
.loopcond:
    cmpl $127, -4(%ebp)
    jge .halt
.print:
    lodsb
    int $0x10
    add $0x1, -4(%ebp)
    jmp .loopcond
.halt:
    jmp .halt
```

The first instruction in the `.loopcond` section compares the variable to 127 (acts like a for loop that iterates 127 times). This works fine and runs the code 127 times before jumping to `.halt`. When I increase the value to be compared however (e.g. to 128), the code seems to jump to `.halt` immediately. I don't understand why this is happening. Is it something about signed integers comparison?

I looked at the objdump, once with 127 and 128:

```
// 127:
00000037 <.loopcond>:
  37:   83 7d fc 7f             cmpl   $0x7f,-0x4(%ebp)
  3b:   7d 09                   jge    46 <.halt>

// 128:
00000037 <.loopcond>:
  37:   81 7d fc 80 00 00 00    cmpl   $0x80,-0x4(%ebp)
  3e:   7d 09                   jge    49 <.halt>
```

I noticed that the operand of the `cmpl` instruction is 4 bytes long in the 128 example, while it's only 1 byte in the 127 example. I suspect that something about that is the cause of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling GAS to assembler for 32-bit mode, but then running that machine code with the CPU in 16-bit mode, so things decode wrong.

---

An earlier guess was that your problem might be related to `add $0x1, -4(%ebp)` which uses an ambiguous operand-size.  If GAS picks byte operand-size, that might cause a problem?  Although if the upper bytes are zero, it would just be zero-extending into the dword.  The cause of your problem is not obvious, but it's weird that you're mixing 16 and 32-bit address size for BP and EBP.

(Update: Instructions other than `mov` with ambiguous operand-size default to dword in GAS, at least for 32 or 64-bit mode.  For 16-bit mode, it defaults to word size, i.e. the non-byte opcode without using a `66` operand-size prefix.  For `mov` it's an error.  Recent GAS versions warn, but still do the default.  Better assemblers like NASM treat it as an error.)

---

Seriously, just put a number in a register and loop with `dec reg` / `jnz` like a normal person.

Or use a debugger to look at memory and sort out what's going on.  Your `cmpl $127, -4(%ebp)` does specify an operand-size so it's definitely doing a dword compare, not treating `128` as `-128` with 8-bit 2's complement.

> I noticed that the operand of the cmpl instruction is 4 bytes long in the 128 example, while it's only 1 byte in the 127 example. I suspect that something about that is the cause of this error.

That's not an error.  Most basic x86 integer ALU instructions have an opcode for a version with an  32-bit immediate, and another with a **sign-extended 8-bit immediate**.

On original 8086 this saved 1 byte for instructions like `cmp r/m16, imm8` vs. `cmp r/m16, imm16`.  In 32/64-bit code, this saves 3 bytes for imm8 vs. imm32.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp lists the forms available.

The cutoff point is of course -128 .. +127 because it's a *sign*-extended immediate.  Your assembler always chooses the smallest encoding possible for a given asm source line, so everything is working as intended.

---

**If you're assembling for 32-bit mode but running as 16-bit mode, `cmpl $imm32, r/m32` will break in a different way than the rest of your code**.

The other instructions are all the same length regardless of mode, but run with the opposite operand-size (16 vs. 32).  But the opcode for `cmpl` and `cmpw` is the same; the difference is only the operand-size (toggled to the non-default-for-the-mode value a `66` prefix).

So when your `cmpl` assembled for 32-bit decodes in 16-bit mode, there are 2 bytes of immediate left over.  Those bytes are `00 00`, which is a memory-destination `add [something], al`  (I forget which registers that `00` modrm encodes in a 16-bit addressing mode.)  This will clobber flags from the `cmp`.

**Use `.code16` or a command-line option to make 16-bit machine code.**

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I'm comparing to -128 instead of comparing to 128, so it's always going to be greater or equal? If so, what do I need to do to actually compare to 128??

Comment: @IanRehwinkel: no, `cmpl $128, something` compares against 128 because you used `cmpl`.  If it was treating it as `-128`, it could encode it using the `83` opcode.

Comment: @IanRehwinkel: oh, that last comment made me realize what your but probably is.  You didn't show how you built your code, but you're probably assembling as 32-bit but then running that machine code in 16-bit mode.  The longer encoding would explain breakage there: **use a debugger** that's configured properly to decode in the mode your CPU is in when you run this.

Comment: jge is a signed jump if greater or equal so you need to make sure the compare is the right size...use jae/jnc for unsigned greater than or equal if that was your desire.